# perl - all possible combinations of hash

Tags: perl, hash, combinations

tell me how to get every possible combination of hash

**Here is an example**

```
my %data = (
'a' => [qw(a1 a2 a3)],
'b' => [qw(b1 b2 b3)],
'c' => [qw(c1 c2 c3)]);
```

**to get**

```
a1
a2
a3
b1
b2
b3
c1
c2
c3

a1 b1
a1 b2
a1 b3
a1 c1
a1 c2
a1 c3

b1 c1
b1 c2
b1 c3
b2 c1
b2 c2
b2 c3
b3 c1
b3 c2
b3 c3

a1 b1 c1
a1 b1 c2
a1 b1 c3
a1 b2 c1
a1 b2 c2
a1 b2 c3
a1 b3 c1
a1 b3 c2
a1 b3 c3
a2 b1 c1
a2 b1 c2
a2 b1 c3
a2 b2 c1
a2 b2 c2
a2 b2 c3
a2 b3 c1
a2 b3 c2
a2 b3 c3
a3 b1 c1
a3 b1 c2
a3 b1 c3
a3 b2 c1
a3 b2 c2
a3 b2 c3
a3 b3 c1
a3 b3 c2
a3 b3 c3
```

thanks

Comment: You said you would like to get every possible combination, yet even when excluding permutations of multiplets containing the same members your example doesn't list all possible combinations - there is no multiplet involving a2, for example. What exactly is your criterion for deciding which combination you want and which one you don't want?

Comment: That's not combination. That's permutation, but only with a subset of the possible derangements. Explain in words the principle that the result set follows, or perhaps the algorithm. - edit: ↑ Yeah, what canavanin said. ↑

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My module [List::Gen](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aGen) contains a `cartesian` function that can produce the results you want.  This code seems to do the trick, but your example does not contain all of the permutations that this will produce, which I am assuming is just an omission in the example.

```
use List::Gen 'cartesian';

my %data = (
    'a' => [qw(a1 a2 a3)],
    'b' => [qw(b1 b2 b3)],
    'c' => [qw(c1 c2 c3)],
);

my $product = cartesian {join ' ' => sort grep defined, @_}
              map {[@$_, undef]} 
              values %data;

say for sort {length $a <=> length $b or $a cmp $b} @$product;
```

That is a bit dense, so to explain:

- `values %data` returns the arrays in `%data`
- `map {[@$_, undef]}` then attaches an empty value to the end of each, since you want the partial combinations
- `cartesian {join ' ' => sort grep defined, @_}` then does the meat of the work, computing the Cartesian product of the arrays while subtracting out the undefined elements, and sorting the values as your example shows.
- `sort {length $a <=> length $b or $a cmp $b} @$product` then prints out the product in the order specified.

Comment: values %data is going to return the values in an indeterminate order; I suspect `@data{ qw/a b c/ }` would be better.

Comment: @ysth => I had `@data{sort keys %data}` before, but I figured that it was a redundant step since the data is being sorted later.

Answer (score 6):

Use brian d foy's [`Set::CrossProduct`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::CrossProduct) module. You'll need to massage your hash into array of arrays in an obvious way.

```
use Set::CrossProduct;
my $iterator = Set::CrossProduct->new( ARRAY_OF_ARRAYS );
my $tuples = $iterator->combinations;
```