# How to find every possible combination of arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, permutation

```
$data = array(
'a' => array('a1', 'a2', 'a3'),
'b' => array('b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'),
'c' => array('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5'));
```

**to get**

```
a1
a2
a3
b1
b2
b3
b4
c1
c2
c3
c4
c5

a1 b1
a1 b2
a1 b3
a1 b4
a1 c1
a1 c2
a1 c3
a1 c4
a1 c5

b1 c1
b1 c2
b1 c3
b1 c4
b1 c5
b2 c1
b2 c2
b2 c3
b2 c4
b2 c5
b3 c1
b3 c2
b3 c3
b3 c4
b3 c5
b4 c1
b4 c2
b4 c3
b4 c4
b4 c5

a1 b1 c1
a1 b1 c2
a1 b1 c3
a1 b1 c4
a1 b1 c5
a1 b2 c1
a1 b2 c2
a1 b2 c3
a1 b2 c4
a1 b2 c5
a1 b3 c1
a1 b3 c2
a1 b3 c3
a1 b3 c4
a1 b3 c5
a1 b4 c1
a1 b4 c2
a1 b4 c3
a1 b4 c4
a1 b4 c5
etc...
```

Thanks

Comment: This question is even less clear than your recent Perl question, which is VERY similar to this one. You should really elaborate a bit on what it is you want to do!

Comment: Why are you asking the same question for two languages? Kind-of-a-dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549529/perl-all-possible-combinations-of-hash

Comment: This should work as a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516599/php-2d-array-output-all-combinations

Comment: It's called "permutations" - Makes it easier to google for. See: http://stereofrog.com/blok/on/070816

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently you want to build the cartesian product of several arrays, i.e. every element combined with each other element.

In addition, you want to have result tuples that omit one or more of those arrays which, for the sake of simplicity, I would model as having a `null` element in each of those arrays:

```
$result = array(array()); // We need to start with one element already, because thats the identity element of the cartesian product
foreach ($data as $arr)
{
    array_push($arr,null); // Add a null element to the array to get tuples with less than all arrays

    // This is the cartesian product:
    $new_result = array();
    foreach ($result as $old_element)
        foreach ($arr as $el)
            $new_result []= array_merge($old_element,array($el));
    $result = $new_result;
}
```

Note that for your result line `a1 b3 c2` this code gives you `array('a1','b3','c2')` and for your result line `b4 c3` this code gives you `array('b4','c3',null)`.

Comment: Appreciated, this algorithm also save my day @AndreKR
from March :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print them all out, just use loops:

```
foreach($data['a'] as $k1 =>$v1){
    $output[]=$v1;
    foreach($data['b'] as $k2 => $v2){
        $output[]=$v2;
        $output[]=$v1."-".$v2;
        foreach($data['c'] as $k3 => $v3){
            $output[]=$v3;
            $output[]=$v1."-".$v2."-".$v3;
        }
    }
}
```

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=168409

Google is awesome that way...

If you want to see how many possibilities there are, multiply them:

```
$count1=1;
$count2=1;
for each $data as $item{
$count2*=count($item);
}
```

Comment: Any way of doing this using a recursive function?

Comment: @Oli: I could do it in python but I never worked with objects in php (It's much better as a procedural language)

Also of note, I missed a line there... you'd need one more for `$v2."-".$v3` so I guess it would be very hard to do in a recursive function (Hence pythons inbuilt `list.product()` function)